# Не получается отправить скрипту php с помощью ajax параметр select

Tags: javascript, ajax

формочка:

```
<form method="POST" id="form1">
  <p align="left"><b>Добавляемая ссылка:</b><br>
   <input type="text" name="link" id="link" size="150" class="form-control">
  </p>
  <p align="left"><b>Имя \ комментарий к ссылке:</b><br>
   <input type="text" name="namelink" id="namelink" size="150" class="form-control" >
  </p>
  <p align="left"><b>Куда относится эта ссылка?</b></p>
  <select class="form-control" >
      <option name="type" id="type1" value="1">1 категория</option>
      <option name="type" id="type1" value="2">2 категория</option>
      <option name="type" id="type1" value="3">3 категория</option>
      <option name="type" id="type1" value="4">4 категория</option>
  </select>
  <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" id="errorBlock"></div>
  <p align="left"><input  type="button" value="Сохранить" id='go' class="btn btn-success mt-2 mb-4 "/></p>
  
</form>
```

Моё извращенство после неё:

```
<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#go').click(function() {
    var link = $('#link').val();
    var namelink = $('#namelink').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax/addlink.php',
        type:'POST',
        cash: false,
        data: {'link' : link, 'namelink' : namelink, 'type' : type},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'Готово') {
                $('#go').text('Сохранено');
                $('#errorBlock').hide();
                document.location.reload(true);
            }
            else {
                $('#errorBlock').show();
                $('#errorBlock').text(data);
                 }
                                 }
    });
});</script>
```

Смысл в том, что как бы я не пробовал изгибнуться ради того что бы передать select, я явно что-то категорически ***не верно*** делаю. Пробовал искать ответы на свою проблему в интернете, но вообще ничего не понятно из примеров приводимых. Подскажите пожалуйста, как заполучить "value" из  и записать его в var type, перед тем как отправить php скрипту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="type" name="type" class="form-control">
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  <option value="1">1 категория</option>
  <option value="2">2 категория</option>
  <option value="3">3 категория</option>
  <option value="4">4 категория</option>
</select>
```

Comment: признаю, затупок), однако всё равно не спасло, после того, как я убрал с "оптиунов" имя и id, и перекинул логику на сам <селект> ничего не поменялось) php скрипт не получил значения :(

Comment: @Manuelka "У меня не работает код php, только я вам его не покажу." Почтальон Печкин

Comment: Пофиксил) спасибо, всё работает)

Comment: @Manuelka Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо назначить имя для `<select>` и по имени его выбирать. Сейчас же я вижу, что вы пытаетесь выбрать значение через атрибут `id="type"`, которого нет в теге `<select>`.

Comment: поставил значение на сам селект, убрал с опций. По имени сам селект тоже пробовал вызывать. Я почти нуль в аджаксе, выучил php :DD